# php mail header not sending correctly

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an HTML email using php. My code is as follows:

```
$to = "test@test.com";
$from = "$senderEmail";
$subject = "Quote Request";
$message = <<<EOF
<html>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<b>Firstname</b> = $senderFirstname<br /><br />
<b>Lastname</b> = $senderLastname<br /><br />
<b>Title</b> = $senderTitle<br /><br />
<b>Company</b> = $senderCompany<br /><br />
<b>Street</b> = $senderStreet<br /><br />
<b>City</b> = $senderCity<br /><br />
<b>State</b> = $senderState<br /><br />
<b>Zip</b> = $senderZip<br /><br />
<b>Phone</b> = $senderPhone<br /><br />
<b>Fax</b> = $senderFax<br /><br />
<b>Email</b> = <a href="mailto:$senderEmail">$senderEmail</a><br /><br />
<b>Installtype</b> = $sendeInstalltype<br /><br />
<b>Facilitytype</b> = $senderFacilitytype<br /><br />
<b>Message</b> = $senderMessage<br />
</body>
</html>
EOF;

$headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

When the mail is sent it comes across as full text with the first line being "Content-type: text/html".  I have used this same script many times before with no problem.  The server it is on is using php 5.1.6 could this be the problem?

Comment: where are you reading the sent email from ?

Comment: Looks alright to me. Make sure [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) is disabled.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for the looking into it.  It is a server issue with the hosting provider that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your script. It is working fine at my end and i am using `PHP 5.1.6`. Check your apache configs. Possibly, something is wrong there.

Comment: It is a setting issue with the hosting provider

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score -2):

possibly yes...
Try to rewrite your code in the "old kind" convention...

```
$var = "blablabla". $another_var . "blablabla";
```